# Zeros of entire functions with parameter

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables

Let $f_w:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be an entire function with $f_w(0)=1$ and at least one root for any choice of $w \in (0,1)$. Assume further that for a dense set of $w$ the function $f_w$ has infinitely many distinct roots and that $w\mapsto f_w$ depends real-analytically on $w.$ Does $f_w$ necessarily have infinitely many distinct roots for all $w \in (0,1)$?

Comment: $f(z)=1-(w-1/2)\sin z$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @ChristianRemling : This function has no zeroes for $w=1/2$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis: This is trivial to fix, of course (for example, consider $(1+z)f$).

Comment: @ChristianRemling : You are right, this is a simper example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$f_w(z)=(1-z)e^z+(2w-1)(e^z-1)$$
is a counterexample.

More specifically, the only root of $f_{1/2}$ is $1$, whereas for each $w\in(0,1)\setminus\{1/2\}$ the function $f_w$ has infinitely many roots, of the form $2w+W_k\left(e^{-2 w}(1-2 w)\right)$, where $k$ is any integer and $W_k$ is the $k$th branch of the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Elementary_properties,_branches_and_range).